# Angular 8 application not running on IE11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, angular8

I've been trying to run my Angular 8 application on IE11.
So far, I have tried all the steps stated in this article,
[Angular 8 and IE 11](https://dev.to/paulinhapenedo/angular-8-and-ie-11-1ed2)

and still getting errors as this picture ->[IE console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Zt9.png)

following are the related files :

***Polyfills.ts:***

```
    /***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */


/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */

import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.


/*

 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`

 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.

 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).

 */
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/

import 'core-js/es/symbol';

import 'core-js/es/promise';

import 'core-js/es/object';

import 'core-js/es/function';

import 'core-js/es/parse-int';

import 'core-js/es/parse-float';

import 'core-js/es/number';

import 'core-js/es/math';

import 'core-js/es/string';

import 'core-js/es/date';

import 'core-js/es/array';

import 'core-js/es/regexp';

import 'core-js/es/map';

import 'core-js/es/weak-map';

import 'core-js/es/set';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

***BROWERSLIST:***

```
// > 0.5%

last 2 versions

Firefox ESR

not dead

 IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

***TSCONFIG.JSON:***

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,

  "compilerOptions": {

    "baseUrl": "./",

    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",

    "sourceMap": true,

    "declaration": false,

    "downlevelIteration": true,

    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "module": "esnext",

    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "importHelpers": true,

    "target": "es5",

    "typeRoots": [

      "node_modules/@types"

    ],

    "lib": [

      "es2018",

      "dom"

    ]
  },

  "angularCompilerOptions": {

    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,

    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

***WEB.CONFIG:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
   
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="100000" />
  </system.web>
 <appSettings>
  
  
 </appSettings>

<system.webServer>
 

     <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRewriteModule" />
        <remove name="UmbracoModule" />
        <remove name="ClientDependencyModule" />
        <remove name="ImageProcessorModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
        preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>


    <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="AddTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <!-- <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="^/(api)" negate="true" /> -->
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/motorclaims/"  />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>

  </configuration>
```

***ANGULAR.JSON:***

```
{

  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",

  "version": 1,

  "newProjectRoot": "projects",

  "projects": {

    "sample": {

      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {

        "@schematics/angular:component": {

          "style": "scss"

        }

      },
      "root": "",

      "sourceRoot": "src",

      "prefix": "app",

      "architect": {
        "build": {

          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/sample",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/css/datepicker.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.mb.slider.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/materialize.js",
              "src/assets/js/messages.js",
              "src/assets/js/select.js",
              "src/assets/js/new_date_picker.js",
              
              "src/assets/js/sample.js",
              "src/assets/Loader.hyperesources/loader_hype_generated_script.js",
              "src/assets/Loader.hyperesources/HYPE-674.thin.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "uat":{
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.uat.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "sample:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "sample:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "sample:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "sample:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "sample:serve:production"
            },
            "uat": {
              "devServerTarget": "sample"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "sample"
  
}
```

***PACKAGE.JSON***

```
  {

  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.36",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^8.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

**Also, the solution should work with ng build.

Comment: As the article said, we don't need to uncomment in **polyfills.ts** at first in Angular 8. To support a new Angular 8 app, you only need to do [these steps](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455#issuecomment-493739768) and modify the **browserslist**. Besides, about the freed script error, I found [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31723). If your project is Angular CLI generated, you can add `(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;` before this line `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';`. Please try these fixes and tell us the result.

Comment: @YuZhou  hi, thank you for your answer there was a script error which was causing the mess. Although, changing es2015 to es5 worked for me.

Comment: Glad to here that you have solved the issue. You can post your solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for helping me. The solution that worked for me is changing

```
"target": "es2015",
```

to

```
"target": "es5",
```

in **tsconfig.json** file. Also, this wasn't working for me before because I had a script file in the assets that was causing the errors. Once I removed it from the project it worked fine on IE11.
So, for future reference, please check your asset files before making any changes for IE11 in order to avoid such errors.